# "На українській" чи "по українській"?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, правопис, українські-словники

Помітила, що деякі пишуть "говорити на українській", а деякі "говорити по українській". Як правильно?

Comment: Якщо ж Вас влаштовують відповіді і Ви їх приймаєте, ставте, будь ласка, прапорець "✔". Таким чином збільшується рейтинг. Дякую за розуміння!

Comment: @ОксанкаСтрус ви можете зайти на сторінку користувача і прочитати коли він останній раз був на сайті. Зараз у AlinaRomanyuk написано *Last seen 48 mins ago*. Тобто вона ще не побачила відповіді;)

Answer (score 4):

На сайті [Мова  - ДНК нації](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/antusurzhuk/govorutu-ukrayinskoyu,-po-ukrayinskomu,-po-ukrayinsku-chu-na-ukrayinskij) картинка коротка відповідає на Ваше питання:[image]

В [Довіднику М.Волощак "Неправильно-Правильно"](http://nepravylno-pravylno.wikidot.com/)

> Розмовляти на українській мові - Розмовляти українською мовою

Answer (score 4):

[Словник української мови 1970-1980 рр.](http://sum.in.ua/s/po-ukrajinsjky) подає такий варіант:

> ПО-УКРАЇНСЬКИ, присл. Те саме, що по-українському.
>
> Між собою часто ми говорили, що є сім'я Косачів, де дітей виховують по-українськи, і що в цій сім'ї є така чудова поетеса (Агатангел Кримський, Вибр., 1965, 503).

На сайті [Мова - ДНК нації](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/antusurzhuk/govorutu-ukrayinskoyu,-po-ukrayinskomu,-po-ukrayinsku-chu-na-ukrayinskij) подають таку інформацію:

> Говорімо українською, по-українськи, по-українському. "Говорити на українській" - калька.

Олександр Авраменко у [Сніданку з 1+1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fRdLCxKWDco) вважає, що:

> **"говорити по-українськи"** - правильна конструкція, але рідковживана;
>
> **"говорити по-українському"** - теж можлива конструкція, але у використанні "не ідеальна"
>
> **"говорити українською"** - найпоширеніший варіант і науковець радить використовувати саме його.

Comment: «Те саме, що по-українському» — тут би дуже пасувала інформація про те, що значить «по-українському» (що це слово має відразу два значення: «як в українців, за звичаєм українців» і «українською мовою»).

Answer (score 3):

«**Говорити українською (мовою)**» — найпоширеніший нині варіант.

«**Говорити по-українськи**» і «**говорити по-українському**» (але не «говорити по українській») теж уживаються, але:

- значно рідше;
- ці вирази теоретично можуть позначати одну з двох речей: або, власне, «говорити українською мовою», або в широкому сенсі «говорити як українець» (що би саме це не мало на увазі: стиль, спосіб мислення абощо). Тож якщо мається на увазі саме мова спілкування (а не щось більш загальне), то варіант «говорити українською (мовою)» дозволяє уникнути неоднозначності.

«**Говорити на українській (мові)**» теж колись казали, але такий варіант фактично майже застарів. «Негайно-ж повинні бути приняті міри, щоб у всіх радянських установах була потрібна кількість урядовців, володіючих українською мовою й щоб на далі всі службовці вміли говорити на українській мові», — писав Володимир Винниченко у 1920, але зараз такий варіант («говорити на якійсь мові») не згадується навіть у словниках. Єдиний випадок, коли іменник «мова» все ще вживається з прийменником «на» — це з дієсловами типу «перекладати» («перекладати на українську мову»), в яких мова виступає наче не «місцем перебування» (місцевий відмінок), а «місцем призначення» (знахідний відмінок), але хоч з ними використання «на якусь мову» все ще нормативне, але й з ними варіант «якоюсь мовою» починає відігравати все більшу роль.

«**Говорити по-українській**» узагалі вийшло з використання. Хоча такий варіант уживав зокрема Іван Нечуй-Левицький («Він привітався до гостей по-українській»; «Софія Леонівна й справді згодом потім нахапалася слів на селі й навчилась таки добре говорити по-українській»; «По-українській говорять пани й батюшки і пани-католики, котрі тутечки навіщось звуть себе поляками, і жиди, бо в тутешніх католиків-панів та дідичів, в тутешніх жидів свій рідний язик — є тільки український»), але зараз він сприймається не те що як застарілий, а навіть як неграмотний.